# latest arch linux on beaglebone black

Tags: kernel, arch-linux

I have installed arch linux using what I assumed was the latest kernel at http://archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-am33x-latest.tar.gz

But this only installs 3.8.13 and I understand that there are users who are using much newer kernels i.e. 3.16

So how do I go about getting the newer kernel as pacman -Syu does not upgrade the kernel and the latest package only appears to use 3.8 ?

This is the kernel info:

```
uname -a
Linux alarm 3.8.13-35-ARCH #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 20:15:28 MDT 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is the name of the kernel the Beaglebone Black runs?

Comment: You'll need the name of the package providing the kernel: `pacman -Q | grep linux`...

Comment: Note that ALARM != Arch.